# Easy way to get ListView filters and sharing setting? not from Salesofrce UI though

Tags: listview, filter, salesforce, sharing

I need to get listview with shared To and filter criteria's in it- Salesforce

Using below queries I am getting error.

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, SobjectType
FROM ListView
WHERE SobjectType = 'Object_Name' AND DeveloperName = 'List_View_DeveloperName'

SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, ListViewId, RowCause
FROM ListViewShare
WHERE ListViewId = 'List_View_Id'
```

I tried via Salesforce Metadata API but eventually had to do it manually.